How to include 3rd party dylib or dll in electron app
I'm using the electron-react-boilerplate package as a starting point for an app.  I also have a native module that gets included and references a 3rd party dynamic library.  I can build and run my app and native module fine in dev mode but when making a deployable app, I get an error:
Library not loaded: @rpath/libndi.dylib

Licensing for the library allows me to bundle with my app so I'd like to copy it from /usr/local/lib/libndi.dylib into my deployable bundle and have it used at runtime.
I've tried adding the following at the top level build section of package.json to no apparent effect (on a mac):
"extraFiles": [
        {
          "from": "/usr/local/lib/libndi.dylib",
          "to": "Contents/Frameworks/",
          "filter": [
            "**/*"
          ]
        }
      ]

How do I instruct gyp or electron-builder to do this properly.

Turns out extraFiles only includes files relative to the root app folder.  The workaround is to copy the file into a local directory and reference it from there.  For example, create a package.json script to copy it:
"prepack": "cp /usr/local/lib/libndi.dylib ./resources/",

Then, reference that location in extraFiles:
"extraFiles": [
        {
          "from": "resources/",
          "to": "Frameworks",
          "filter": [
            "libndi.dylib"
          ]
        }
      ]

Mac libs should be placed in Frameworks/.  Windows dlls go into the root (untested by me).
